# Download Script iCloud Photo Sharing web album

Tags: javascript, jquery, icloud

I am trying to write a script that goes through all the photos in a iCloud Photo Sharing web album and downloads them all.

I manually go here: https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0Q5oqs3qGtDCal;09534761-7F89-49B0-8AFD-4CA5EB2D91AC

Now the script should do the following automatically:

1. Click on the download button - download photo
2. Click on the next arrow (if it is not the last photo)
3. repeat above (if not last photo)

I have the following, yet the "trigger" events simply do not work.

Any help?

```
function dl(){
        $('.right-container .download').trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.x-next-slideshow-item').trigger('click');
            setTimeout(function(){
                if($('.x-next-slideshow-item').length){
                    console.log('has next');
                    dl();
                }
            },1000);
        },1000);
    } dl();
```

Comment: Did you every get this to work? Are you trying to create a slideshow from the photos in your iCloud shared album?

Comment: Never got it to work properly. Photos are not in right order, sometimes even broken (like half the image is white) etc. -> Ended up using paralles desktop with mac os to sign into that icloud account and download the photos in the photos app there...